# Starting Vagrant Machine on Windows 7 [32 bit] is stucked

Tags: windows-7, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have just studied Vagrant. My computer is Window 7 [32bit]. I have installed the latest version "vagrant_1.7.2" then I run commands to start visual machine but it has never completed. See picture below:
[image: Commands to start my Vagrant Machine]

I try to search to resolve this problem, some one say that Vagrant using "default config" because my computer contain "Cygwin" program but when try to run Vagrant from new computer this bug still occur.

Here is content in my "Viagrantfile"

> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|   config.vm.box =
>   "hashicorp/precise32" end

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think Windows 7 has Hyper-V enabled.

Comment: Windows 7 has virtualisation feature disabled by default. You meed to enable the virtualisation mode from the bios and then perform the same. If you have problem further,comment here...

Comment: I think problem is "Bringing machine 'default" ...... So Viagrant did not run my "Viagrantfile"

Comment: shekhar suman I have enable "virtualisation mode" but it still occur

Comment: "Bringing machine 'default' up with 'hyperv' provider..."